# Is there a way to see a list of unreachable revisions in Bazaar?

Tags: bazaar

If I do an `uncommit`, Bazaar gives me a revision id which I can use to retrieve the uncommitted revision, should I ever need it. If I don't write it down right after the `uncommit`, is there a way to find this revision id again?

Similarly, if I delete a branch from a shared repository, the unique revisions of the branch remain in the shared repository, but how can I find their revision ids?

Common in both of these cases is that the revisions are "unreachable", since they are not part of any branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a solution in the bzrtools package with its "heads" subcommand.

1. Install package [bzrtools [image: Install bzrtools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bzrtools). Then proceed to your project.
2. Proceed to your project and enter:

   `bzr heads --dead-only`

(From [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.bazaar-ng.general/74129))